# programmatically change matplotlib fill data

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm creating an animation using Matplotlib and I'm using a Fill object. I'd like to be able to change the fill data from a function. For other plot types there's usually a `set_data()` function or `set_offsets()`. Fill doesn't seem to have one. I would expect to do something like the code below but this doesn't work. Any ideas?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(-1, 1), ylim=(-1, 1),)
triangle, = ax.fill([0,1,1],[0,0,1])
# I want to change the datapoints later in my code, like this:
triangle.set_data([0,2,2],[0,0,2])
```

Comment: What type of object is `triangle`?  Did you look up the documentation for that type?  I can understand why you would _want_ that code to work, but why do you think it _should_?

Comment: `triangle` is a `fill` object, which is a `Polygon`, which I would think would have a way to change it's data.

Comment: Did you look at http://matplotlib.org/api/artist_api.html#matplotlib.patches.Polygon ?

Comment: Yes. Not obvious if there's a way to change the data. Hence my question. I'd be open to another suggestion for manipulating the data to a closed,filled, object.

Comment: `set_xy`? http://matplotlib.org/api/artist_api.html#matplotlib.patches.Polygon.set_xy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not particularly well documented, but `Polygon` objects have a pair of methods `get_xy` and `set_xy`.  The method `get_xy()` returns an ndarray with shape (N + 1, 2).  The extra point is a repeat of the first point (so that the polygon is closed).  Putting the desired data into the expected format (which is what is specified in the documentation to construct a `Polygon` object):

```
triangle.set_xy(np.array([[0, 2, 2, 0],[0, 0, 2, 0]]).T)
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_xlim([0, 3])
ax.set_ylim([0, 3])
plt.draw()
```

This even lets you change the number of vertices in your patch.

Added issue to clarify the documentation https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/3035.